# How to display my data (molecules)?

Tags: software-rec, scientific-linux

In my code I generate a .dat file which is of the format:

> x \t y \t z \t charge \t type \t ID

There are about 3000 lines in the file and I want to display sphere (of radius 1 in my units). I tried to use `paraview`, `pymol` and `rasmol`. Paraview doesn't understand my file format. With pymol and rasmol I couldn't understand how they loaded my data. Do any of you know how to load data which is not in pdb format into pymol or rasmol? Also, I want to color the beads according to the last 3 properties is there any other way?

I should note that I need the ability to browse through the 3d picture I get.

My question might not be clear so please ask me for any clarification I might give.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know what tag to give this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is pretty obvious -- convert your data to the format accepted by the program you would like to use (idea the program should somehow read your custom format is, ekhem, naive?).